# Should I auto-generate ASP.NET Pages or attempt to cache them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Let's say I have database containing all sorts of information on cars (color, make, model, engine, etc), and am tasked with building specific (but large) list of web-pages for it. For example:

- www.example.com/fords.aspx
- www.example.com/hondas.aspx
- www.example.com/dark-cars.aspx
- www.example.com/bright-cars.aspx

The final output of these pages **is not static**, but the data retrieved from the database query is. I can write a tool that will generate these pages all in advance, or attempt to generate them dynamically and rely on caching. For instance:

- www.example.com/dynamic.aspx?make=fords

But the last time I looked into ASP.NET/IIS7 caching, it didn't seem like it was suited for this (the specific type of caching mechanism I would have needed to use seemed to have a separate cache for each user to the site, rather than a single shared one). Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: If data queries are complex you may consider summary tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you cache the data being pulled from the database in the global `Cache` object then it will be available to all users across your site.

Also if you decide to use something like `OutputCache` and set the Location to Server it will also be available globally.